# How can I stop a file creation process running?

Tags: macos, bash

My friend and I were messing around with our computers bash_profiles and one of us (...) wrote an infinite loop that creates a file on his desktop. The pseudo code looks like this:

```
i=1
while(i > 0)
do
    i=++
    echo filename$i
done
```

The script ran for about ten seconds creating 200,000 files on his desktop. Now the computer is trying to process the files. Does anyone know how to kill it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original poster's computer can't open up the Task Manager (or Activity Monitor, actually :-) because the Finder is busy trying to digest the thousands of files created on the Desktop.  Sounds like an awful mess (that you'll never do again, eh?)

In any event, I'd recommend starting your Macintosh in [Single User mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_user_mode).

Details are here:  http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1492

You can then rm all those bogus files from the Desktop from there.

I hope this answer helps!

Answer (score 0):

you could open task manager, and try to kill it that way, or you could go to processes and kill it that way, or just hit the power button.

Word of advice:
Next time don't try that.

And you may still have to delete those files. (They may be off the desktop visible screen, so navigate to your desktop folder)

Answer (score 0):

Find out the PID of your amoking script, and kill it (`kill 123456`). Afterwards, change to the Desktop directory and do `rm filename*`, provided that only these files start with `filename`.

Answer (score 0):

As one of the other responses said, if you know the process ID use `kill <pid>` or `kill -9 <pid>`. But if that information is not available to you, from a terminal you can use top to do that.

You can start top as `top -U $USER` to show only processes owned by the current user. Once top is running you can sort the processes by whatever you wish by pressing F or O. I would suggest listing by the command name (if you remember which one you ran) or by CPU usage (default). Once you find out the PID, you can kill the process with the k key.

For help with key bindings you can press ? or h.